# Set property value when all threads are finished?

Tags: c#, multithreading

In my application there are three threads like:

```
 private Thread _analysisThread;
 private Thread _head2HeadThread;
 private Thread _formThread;
```

and each thread is started in the following way:

```
if (_analysisThread == null || !_analysisThread.IsAlive)
{
     _analysisThread = new Thread(() => { Analysis.Logic(match); });
     _analysisThread.Start();
}
```

I've a ListView where the user can select an item and then start again the thread, but I want prevent this 'cause the methods inside each thread are heavy, so need time to complete them.

Until now I want disable the `ListView` selection, so I did:

```
<ListView IsEnabled="{Binding IsMatchListEnabled}">

private bool _isMatchListEnabled = true;
public bool IsMatchListEnabled
{
    get { return _isMatchListEnabled; }
    set
    {
        _isMatchListEnabled = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

before a new Thread start I do: `IsMatchListEnabled = false;` but what I need to do is check if all thread are finished and then do: `IsMatchListEnabled = true;`, actually if I enable the `ListView` after all thread, I get the `ListView` even enabled 'cause the `Thread` code is async, and the code outside the `Thread` is sync, so actually this property is useless.

What I tried to avoid this is create an infinite loop like this:

```
while (true)
{
   if (!_analysisThread.IsAlive && !_head2HeadThread.IsAlive && !_formThread.IsAlive)
   {
          IsMatchListEnabled = true;
          break;
   }
}
```

this loop is placed after all threads execution, but as you can imagine, this will freeze the application.
Any solution?

Comment: Use `Task`s instead of threads. `Task` provide normal ways to wait for completion. You _can_ do that with Threads if you insist, but there is not much reason to.

Comment: @Evk that's right, thanks for the hint :

Comment: You wrote fire-and-forget threaded code.  You can almost never forget.  Do not use Thread, use the convenient helper classes that help you to not forget.  BackgroundWorker, Task, perhaps async/await.  And be sure to read up on this, threading will eat you alive and spit out your bones when you don't understand it well enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All comments are correct — it's better to use `Tasks`. Just to answer OP's question.

You can synchronize threads with `ManualResetEvent`, having an array of events by the number of threads and one additional thread to change `IsMatchListEnabled` when all threads are finished.

```
public static void SomeThreadAction(object id)
{
    var ev = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    events[id] = ev; // store the event somewhere

    Thread.Sleep(2000 * (int)id); // do your work

    ev.Set(); // set the event signaled
}
```

Then, somewhere else we need to initialize waiting routine.

```
// we need tokens to be able to cancel waiting
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var ct = cts.Token;

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    bool completed = false;
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested && !completed)
    {
        // will check if our routine is cancelled each second
        completed = 
            WaitHandle.WaitAll(
                events.Values.Cast<ManualResetEvent>().ToArray(),
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); 
    }

    if (completed) // if not completed, then somebody cancelled our routine
        ; // change your variable here
});
```

Complete example can be found and viewed [here](https://gist.github.com/CassandraDied/47e53662d3b2a6ca1c5be4a47eb1c093).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this. It's more powerful than tasks and the code is far simpler than using threads.

Let's say you have 3 long-running operations:

```
Action huey = () => { Console.WriteLine("Huey Start"); Thread.Sleep(5000); Console.WriteLine("Huey Done"); };
Action dewey = () => { Console.WriteLine("Dewey Start"); Thread.Sleep(5000); Console.WriteLine("Dewey Done"); };
Action louie = () => { Console.WriteLine("Louie Start"); Thread.Sleep(5000); Console.WriteLine("Louie Done"); };
```

Now you can write the following simple query:

```
IObservable<Unit> query =
    from a in new [] { huey, dewey, louie }.ToObservable()
    from u in Observable.Start(() => a())
    select u;
```

You run it like this:

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
IDisposable subscription = query.Subscribe(u => { }, () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("All Done in {0} seconds.", sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
});
```

The results I get are:

```
Huey Start
Dewey Start
Louie Start
Huey Done
Louie Done
Dewey Done
All Done in 5.0259197 seconds.
```

Three 5 second operations complete in 5.03 seconds. All in parallel.

If you want to stop the computation early just call `subscription.Dispose()`.

NuGet "System.Reactive" to get the bits.

Comment: What will happen in case of exception in any of the threads? Will it be re-thrown near `subscription.Subscribe`?

Comment: @cassandrad - No, not with the code I posted, but there is another overload of the `.Subscribe` method that will take an exception if one is thrown. You can also put in `.Retry` operators on observables to retry some code that fails due to an exception.